# how to get config data from appsettings.json with asp.net core & react

Tags: c#, node.js, reactjs, asp.net-core, redux

I'm using asp.net core with react/redux and i'm trying to move my config data that is in react/redux into the appsettings.json file. But once the config data has been moved; how is the config data accessible to the ClientApp?

I'm using the Reactjs with Redux starter for ASP.NET Core.

**update**

If this is not the recommended way to store app configs please let me know what is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend reading the config file from your client side. But if you want to do I would suggest you create a service that read the json file and expo some configuration for client side.

You can config from ASP.Net Core side like this

Example you have config like this in your json

```
 "EmailSettings": {
    "MailServer": "",
    "MailPort": ,
    "Email": "",
    "Password": "",
    "SenderName": "",
    "Sender": "",
    "SysAdminEmail": ""
  },
```

So you need to define the matching model with config

```
public class EmailSettings
{
  public string MailServer { get; set; }
  public int MailPort { get; set; }
  public string SenderName { get; set; }
  public string Sender { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string SysAdminEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Then register in Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<EmailSettings>(configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
```

So you can use in your service

```
private readonly IOptions<EmailSettings> _emailSetting;

public EmailSender(IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSetting)
{
  _emailSetting = emailSetting;
} 

public string GetConfig(){
    return _emailSetting.Value.SenderName;
}
```

Comment: isn't the appsettings.json the recommended place to store config data for an asp.net application? Why don't you recommend using appsettings.json?

Comment: No what I mean you expo the config data for client side and client can see it. Configuration from sever side are sensitive because it may contain your production code, database etc. So what I mean dont expo the config for user to see if you dont have any good reason to do that

Comment: okay but am I right that this is the place to put all app config data?

Comment: okay thank you. I have been working with react for years but just started with asp.net.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to manage independently client and server configurations.

For server configurations management the `appsettings.json` is the right place.

In the client you can handle the configurations as environment variables in the following way:

1. create a configuration file for each environment, for example:

   .env.dev
   .env.test
   .env.prod

Suppose you have "SOME_URL" variable in each file:

*.env.dev*:

```
SOME_URL=http://localhost:4000/
```

*.env.test*

```
SOME_URL=http://mytesturl/
```

and so on and so forth

2. Use webpack environment plugin:

   plugins: options.plugins.concat([
   new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
   SOME_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.SOME_URL),
   ...
   }),
   ]),
3. this is the script I use for launching the app:

   "start": "cross-env env-cmd -f .env.dev node server",
4. Access the configuration in the client:

   process.env.SOME_URL;
5. npm i env-cmd

With webpack you are using bundled code that runs in the browser. The `process.env` context doesn’t exist in the browser. The way it works is that you’ve told the webpack Environment plugin that the value of `process.env.SOME_URL` should be available in the bundled client code. When bundling, the plugin simply looks for the exact text `process.env.SOME_URL` in the code and replaces it with the actual value.