# How Can I read Appsettings.json file from react.js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs

I need to get or read the App settings file from `react`. Dynamically read or get the values from the app settings. How can I integrate this requirement in my application?

Comment: Maybe this is will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568796/how-to-store-configuration-file-and-read-it-using-react

Comment: Where is the file located in relation to the app?  If it is bundled with the app then it is a simple `import`, otherwise, a fairly simple GET request. Can you provide more details about your use-case? Try to be as specific as possible in order to get a quicker and/or more accurate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get config data from appsettings.json with asp.net core & react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446428/how-to-get-config-data-from-appsettings-json-with-asp-net-core-react)